# Accessing pieces of bitmaps inside a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieclip with 10 bitmaps in it. I wanna access each of them.

myMovieClip is the movieclip containing those 10 bitmaps. I wanna access those bitmaps one by one. All 10 bitmaps are imported separately. 
I tried this :

```
for ( var i =0 ; i< myMovieClip.numChildren ; i++)
{


    trace ( myMovieClip.getChildAt(i) ); 

}
```

Problem is numChildren comes "1" only, as if it doesnot consider those 10 pieces of bitmap. Any other way, to access those bitmaps ?

thanks
V.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're doing? Like, how is the movieclip with 10 bitmaps in it (incidentally, I assume "pieces of bitmaps" are in fact separate bitmaps; either remove "pieces" or explain what that means) created in the first place

Comment: you said it best "10 pieces of bitmaps in it" you need to convert them to movieClips.

Comment: `trace(myMovieClip.getChildAt(0) is DisplayObjectContainer);`, if that returns a value of `true` then the "10 pieces of bitmaps" might be inside another `DisplayObjectContainer` object. If so you might need to do the following `(myMovieClip.getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(i);`. This is just a guess based on the vague information you have provided within your question.

Comment: Scratch what I said earlier(unless it's right), I think I know what's happening. OP created a movieclip symbol in flash professional and the "10 pieces of bitmaps" are bitmap images he added to the symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what do you mean by pieces of bitmaps?? Do you mean 10 different bitmap objects are children of the movieClip??

In addition, your code does have a syntax error.

```
var newMc:MovieClip = MovieClip();
```

should be:

```
var newMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
```

second off all, in your loop, numChildren will be always changing since you are taking the reference of a child from the myMoiveClip and moving it to the newMc object.  there are two way to fix this.

either set a local variable to the value of myMovieClip.numChildren and use that value in your loop
example:

```
var numOfChildren:int = myMovieClip.numChildren;
for(var i:int = 0; i < numOfChildren; i++){
     var newMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();    
     newMc.addChild(myMovieClip.getChildAt(i)); 
}
```

this will move the bitmaps out of myMovieClip and into newMc, if you want to keep them there you can create a new bitmap inside the loop and then add the new bitmap to the newMc.
example:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < myMovieClip.numChildren; i++){
     var newMc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); 
     var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(Bitmap(myMovieClip.getChildAt(i)).bitmapData);   
     newMc.addChild(b);
}
```

Comment: the mc "myMovieClip" contains 10 bitmaps. myMovieClip.numChildren would always be "1" ( Your loop would run only once ). But i have imported 10 separate bitmaps. How to access each of them ?

Comment: Are you using an adobe Flash professional application to create your project?  If so, you have to right click on each bitmap (in the libaray) you are sticking inside the movieclip and select properties. Then press the actionscript tab and check the box for "export for actionscript".  You can also give each bitmap a class name.  Then access the bitmaps as I stated above.  you can then also access them individually by the class name if you like as well.